# How to use "Sign In With Google" together with TokenClient?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-identity

I read the information and examples from the [*Sign in with Google* Guides](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) and the [Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK Guides](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview) and I managed to set up authorization using Tokens to Google Cloud APIs. Unfortunately, I still get a login prompt to select my Google Account every time I load the page even after the user consent has been given on first login.

I saw that [`requestAccessToken` allows specifying a user email as `hint` via `OverridableTokenClientConfig`](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#OverridableTokenClientConfig) for the login, but even if I specify the `hint` I still get the login prompt every time `requestAccessToken` is running.

Ultimately, I want to use *Sign in with Google* to allow the user to [automatically sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out) and provide user information like email to the app. Then `requestAccessToken` should use that email to request the token without prompting the user again (except for the first time where the user needs to give consent to the `devstorage.full_control` scope).

This is the current code I'm using (to run it, you need to insert a valid clientId, bucket and object):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Google Identity Service see https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gis-and-gapi -->
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initTokenClient()" async defer></script>
    <script>
        var tokenClient;
        var access_token;
        var clientId = '123456789012-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz123456.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var email = 'florian.feldhaus@gmail.com'
        var bucket = 'private-bucket'
        var object = 'private-object.json'

        function initTokenClient() {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
                callback: (tokenResponse) => {
                    access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
                },
            });
        }

        function getToken() {
            // Re-entrant function to request user consent.
            // Returns an access token to the callback specified in google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient
            // Use a user gesture to call this function and obtain a new, valid access token
            // when the previous token expires and a 401 status code is returned by Google API calls.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({
                    hint: email
                }
            );
        }

        function getObject() {
            fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/' + bucket + '/o/' + object + '?alt=media', {
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(content => console.log(content))
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>      
    <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button>
    <button onclick="getObject()">Load Object</button>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Getting the access token always opens a login prompt like this

[image: Login Prompt]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [login prompt can be prevented by setting an empty `prompt` parameter in `initTokenClient`](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#TokenClientConfig). This will only prompt for the login and user consent on the first login. All further logins will use the selected account from the first login. This still briefly shows a popup with a spinning wheel which usually is gone within a second.

If someone has more information to share on how to get rid of the popup and integrate with *Sign in with Google* please share as a separate answer.

My full example now looks like this (removing `hint` and adding `prompt`):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Google Identity Service see https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gis-and-gapi -->
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initTokenClient()" async defer></script>
    <script>
        var tokenClient;
        var access_token;
        var clientId = '123456789012-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz123456.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var email = 'florian.feldhaus@gmail.com'
        var bucket = 'private-bucket'
        var object = 'private-object.json'

        function initTokenClient() {
            tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: clientId,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
                prompt: '',
                callback: (tokenResponse) => {
                    access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
                },
            });
        }

        function getToken() {
            // Re-entrant function to request user consent.
            // Returns an access token to the callback specified in google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient
            // Use a user gesture to call this function and obtain a new, valid access token
            // when the previous token expires and a 401 status code is returned by Google API calls.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
        }

        function getObject() {
            fetch('https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/' + bucket + '/o/' + object + '?alt=media', {
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(content => console.log(content))
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>      
    <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button>
    <button onclick="getObject()">Load Object</button>    
  </body>
</html>
```